# Couldn't type anything in tinyMCE's modal

Tags: php, html, laravel, tinymce

Excuse me. I have a problem with tinyMCE. So, the problem is i couldn't type anything in tinyMCE's modal. Usually when we insert a media or link using tinyMCE, there's always a modal like this:

[tinyMCE's modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUkTv.png)

I want to type the link but it can't. When i try in another project folder (ex: folder B), it works fine. But only in this project (folder A) the problem was show up. I'll show the path of tinyMCE in my project folder (tinyMCE folder is in bower_components folder). Here :

[tinyMCE's folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwzfW.png)

And this is the script that i linked to index file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bower_components/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/sweetalert2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
            external_plugins: {
                'tiny_mce_wiris' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js'
            },
            selector: 'textarea#materi',
            height: 200,
            plugins: 'print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars emoticons',
            imagetools_cors_hosts: ['picsum.photos'],
            menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media template link anchor codesample | ltr rtl | tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor | tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry',
            toolbar_sticky: true,
            autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
            autosave_interval: '30s',
            autosave_prefix: '{path}{query}-{id}-',
            autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
            autosave_retention: '2m',  
            image_caption: true,
            quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
            noneditable_noneditable_class: 'mceNonEditable',
            toolbar_mode: 'sliding',
            content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
        });
</script>
```

By the way i have a modal in my index file but it separate with that index file. In that modal file, there's a textarea with id="materi"

And i don't linked the jquery in index file but in a _script.blade.php at component folder.

So could you tell me what happen? Why i could't type in tinyMCE's modal? Help me please. Thank you.